# Popups - Possible to avoid blocking?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I've noticed on some sites that I get a popup window when clicking on a link, and it doesn't get blocked!

An example is unblockbypass.com, a proxy bypassing website.

I thought all popups get blocked, but I can't find an explicit answer on this.

Is there a way to make a popup a link, and in this way, avoid getting it blocked?

Teach me your magic.

#### UPDATE - I AM NOT EVIL

I hate popups too. I am not who you think I am - one of *them* - *shudder*.

I am developing an internal Single Page Application for the organization I work for, and a user can click to open up an app or applet in a separate window, similar to how Gmail can popout their chat window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about the way the popup is invoked. To open the popup we use window.open() function. If this function is called on an onclick event of an A element for example, this is considered an user action so the blocker let the popup proceed. If it's called in other events or functions the blocker do block the action "not requested".

to block all the popups the blocker would have to block any other link click.

Comment: Okay. Now, can you still manipulate the opening on the onclick event, such as customize the width and height based on new data since obtained in the app, etc.? How does the browser know that you are still coming from an onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't researched how to annoyingly invade people's user experience, so my knowledge is limited. But the way I understand it, most of the less-intrusive popup blockers will block popups *unless* their creation is initiated from a click on the page. This is because in many cases, clicking a link or button on a page is *intended* to trigger a popup - one that's very relevant to the content you're viewing.

So, many advertisers abuse this fact to simply show their popups when the user clicks any random spot on the page. You may be able to find popup blockers (or customize the one you have) that will block new dialogs regardless of the cause - but this will mean that on some sites that innocently make use of them, you will need to manually allow their popups.

Comment: Don't worry man, I know popups are **evil**. This is for an internal organizational SPA where the user definitely intends to do it.